# Immutabily of a class in java

Tags: java, immutability

Does a class's immutability depend only on its fields ?

If a class has a member class that is not marked final but marked as "static class" and the members of this inner class are also final,,, and all the fields of the enclosing outer class is marked final, then how the immutability will be described for the outer class ?

Comment: Immutability is a general term and has no concrete definition. E.g. if class has a final list field is it immutable? List can be modified in some situations so actually it is not immutable class. I think it's more philosophical discussion, not a concrete one.

Comment: Note that a class being final has precious little to do with immutability.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not depend.

In wider sense, a class is *immutable* if all method calls anytime will return the same result.

Good example is `java.lang.String` class, where the `hashcode` field is *changed* when you call `hashcode()` first time, but *the returned result is the same*.

More strict interpretation is when *no fields can be changed* after initialization. It can be achieved e.g. by not declaring public setters, and avoiding any alteration inside the class. Other way is - as you mentioned - declaring fields as `final.`

Comment: What about classes like "Scheduler" that has method `schedule` that returns `void`. Does it immutable? I like definition from wiki: "In object-oriented and functional programming, an immutable object is an object whose state cannot be modified after it is created." Here is another term "state" that also has vague definition :)

Comment: Yeah, if that `Scheduler` does not provide `getScheduledJobs()` or any similar method whose result would change after calling `schedule()`, it may be considered immutable. But I intentionally left *state* out of the answer, 'cause that would lead to different interpretations (state within an object or within other objects, threads, etc.)